# What is the best way to store key value pairs in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have an angular app that consists of a main page and partial pages. Partial pages are displayed in `ui-view`

```
<div class="" ui-view>

</div>
```

To store a global variable I use `$scope.$parent.variable_name`. So I declared the variable in the base controller:

```
$scope.$parent.my_array = [];
```

and attempted to fill it from the partial page controller using:

```
 $scope.$parent.my_array.push({ 'KeyId': KeyVariableID, 'KeyValue': KeyValue });
```

but that does not seem to do anything. Can anyone help?

Comment: Use services to share data and methods across various parts of the app

Comment: Use angular service to share the data across the app. yourAppModule.service('shareDataService', function(){
  // setter && // getter method define here 
});

Comment: [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) is. It is built-in generic storage service with some simple features. Sure, you can build your own service instead, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I ended up using the following service:

```
.service('MyService', function() {
  // Create a reference to ourself
  var sv = this;

  // Initialise the data structure
  sv.data = { };

  // Function to set an item in the map
  sv.setItem = function(key, value) {
    sv.data[key] = value;
  }

  // Function to retrieve a value from the map
  sv.getItem = function(key) {
    if (sv.data[key] != undefined) {
      return sv.data[key];
    }
    return false;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$rootScope` can work, but I find it can get a bit messy tracking down the source of properties set on it.

Instead, Services can be used to hold state. If you have a Service that is the single source of truth for some state (key-value) object, you do not need to worry about inheriting some $rootScope property or parent controller property.

Relying on the built in `$cacheFactory` provider, your service could look like:

```
angular.factory('myCache', function myCacheFactory($cacheFactory) {
  return $cacheFactory('my-cache');
}
```

Now, you can include the `myCache` service in any of your controllers and use it as described in the `$cacheFactory` documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

Comment: but how do I pass in and set the values in my service?